# How to make a flash file fit the entire browser window?

Tags: javascript, flash

I'm an absolute beginner at flash so please bear with me. I'm using Adobe Flash CS4

I'm currently trying to fit a flash intro inside the browser window (height 100%, width 100%). I've tried changing the height, width attributes but with no luck. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the publish settings, under HTML, for the Dimensions setting, select percentage and set height and width to 100%. Then publish the SWF and HTML. Note: you can also accomplish this in the HTML file loading the Flash object by setting the `width` and `height` attributes of the `embed` object to `100%`, and the `scale` attribute to `exactfit`.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Only problem now is that the menu I have and the logo looks screwy because it's not proportional anymore. How do I fit only the background, while maintaining the menu & logo proportional?

Comment: That process is a bit more involved. You'll need to disable the automatic scaling of the entire SWF document, set up an object to listen for resizing events and adjust the position and size of each individual movie clip as these events occur. Here is a tutorial with examples: http://www.tutorio.com/tutorial/liquid-flash-layout